# Error when running cling 2.0 Browser example in Android

Tags: android, upnp

I am trying to use Cling 2.0 on Android 4.1 and up to be a upnp renderer and server.
I get the following error when the the Browser example runs:

```
Process: com.mike.cling_test, PID: 8846
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/eclipse/jetty/server/Server;
at org.fourthline.cling.transport.impl.jetty.JettyServletContainer.resetServer(JettyServletContainer.java:165)
at org.fourthline.cling.transport.impl.jetty.JettyServletContainer.<init>(JettyServletContainer.java:57)
            at org.fourthline.cling.transport.impl.jetty.JettyServletContainer.<clinit>(JettyServletContainer.java:55)
```

I have googled the error and I found [Cling User forum](http://4thline.org/projects/mailinglists.html#nabble-td4025642)

I have followed the steps outlined in the the answer, but i still get the same error. The online manual does not seem to be the one I should be using. Is there a pdf of the version 2.0 manual?

Comment: I've tidied up the formatting of the question but I'm afraid it still isn't very clear.  Also, requests for links to off-site resources are considered off topic for this site.  Can you edit to add code (a short, full program) which demonstrates the problem?  That'd help turn this question into something that isn't dependent on the content of a third party's web site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i had the same issue, the problem is cling is provided without jetty library.

You have to use maven dependency like this:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-client</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Or if, like me, you use Android studio, update your gradle script:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile files('src/libs/cling-core-2.0.1.jar')
    compile files('src/libs/cling-support-2.0.1.jar')
    compile files('src/libs/seamless-http-1.1.0.jar')
    compile files('src/libs/seamless-util-1.1.0.jar')
    compile files('src/libs/seamless-xml-1.1.0.jar')
    compile 'org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:8.1.8.v20121106'
    compile 'org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-client:8.1.8.v20121106'
    compile 'org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:8.1.8.v20121106'    
}
```

Hope that help.